# SUBSTRING To split column name get first and last base on the space

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have NAME column data like

| NAME |
| --- |
| Victoria Brown |
| Sam Allen JR |
| Ray M James III |

I want to split base on the number of space the firstname, lastname.
HERE is what I did but last case statement is coming wrong it still getting the suffix when we have 3 space.

expecting:

| NAME |
| --- |
| Victoria Brown |
| Sam Allen |
| Ray James |

```
SELECT
LEN (NAME ) - LEN (REPLACE (NAME, ' ', '')),
CASE 
    WHEN LEN(NAME) - LEN(REPLACE(NAME, ' ', '')) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(NAME, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', NAME) - 1) 
    WHEN LEN(NAME) - LEN(REPLACE(NAME, ' ', '')) = 2 THEN SUBSTRING (NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', NAME, (CHARINDEX(' ', NAME) +1)) +1, LEN(NAME)) 
    WHEN LEN(NAME) - LEN(REPLACE(NAME, ' ', '')) = 3 THEN SUBSTRING (NAME, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', NAME) - 1) 
END AS FIRSTNAME,

CASE 
    WHEN LEN(NAME) - LEN(REPLACE(NAME, ' ', '')) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', NAME) + 1, LEN(NAME))
    WHEN LEN(NAME) - LEN(REPLACE(NAME, ' ', '')) = 2 THEN SUBSTRING (NAME, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', NAME) - 1)
    WHEN LEN(NAME) - LEN(REPLACE(NAME, ' ', '')) = 3 THEN SUBSTRING (NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', NAME, (CHARINDEX(' ', NAME) +1)) +1, LEN(NAME) - CHARINDEX(' ', NAME, (CHARINDEX(' ', NAME) +1)) +1) 
END AS LASTNAME

FROM INFOS
```

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: @Ullas added the expectation, basically fist and lastname only

Comment: You'll probably want to read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). :)

Comment: This always feels like a losing battle against death-from-a-thousand-edge-cases. But... if I'm understanding your logic, you are detecting how many words you find in a name and then picking out the words, by position, that are "first" and "last" names. What RDBMS are you using? IF "Sql Server", what version?

Comment: What about adding Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Catherine Zeta-Jones, Jan Lodewijk Willem de Geer van Jutphaas and Carl van der Walt to your sample data?

Comment: Push back on whoever is supplying this data as one big string to fix their bad data and give it to you properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If string_split is available in your version

> ```
> select *
> from infos
> cross apply (
>   select 
>     max(case when rn = 1 then value else '' end) as firstname 
>   , max(case 
>         when parts = 2 and rn = 2 then value
>         when parts > 2 and rn = parts - 1 then value
>         else ''
>         end) as lastname
>   from 
>   (
>     select value
>     , rn = row_number() over (order by (select null))
>     , parts = count(*) over ()
>     from string_split(name, ' ') spl
>   ) q
> ) ca;
> ```

| id | name | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Victoria Brown | Victoria | Brown |
| 2 | Sam Allen JR | Sam | Allen |
| 3 | Ray M James III | Ray | James |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d1490edcf894c9eac70da5f5d53f5848)*

Comment: Like @JNevill said, losing battle. Change your last row of sample data to `('Ray Marcus James III')`, for example. (To avoid any suspense, [it breaks in two ways](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0742ecffbf74c7e2f47c79408b8243e7).)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for pointing that out. Well, fixing that bug was weird.

Comment: But [it still thinks `Marcus` is Ray's last name](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f6a42be2f535e72ca3bd1c5a420c692d), because you are ordering by the length of the name for some reason (I chose 6 characters on purpose, but basically, no, you can't practically solve all edge cases).

Comment: Ok, I suppose the last name is more towards the end. I sorted by length because I think that logic of `(if n parts then take x)` is worse.